# how can i start the screensaver (and lock the screen) from the os x terminal?

Tags: macos

Is there a way to start the screensaver (and lock the screen) from a bash script?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine
```

**Update for macOS High Sierra:**

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine
```

**Update for macOS Sonoma:**

```
open /System/Library/CoreServices/ScreenSaverEngine.app
```

Comment: If you copy that app into your user's Applications folder you can invoke it with spotlight (helpful if you want a keyboard-driven solution).

Comment: You can also simply just use: `open -a ScreenSaverEngine`

Comment: this will not work on high sierra anymore, but you can still use `open -a ScreenSaverEngine`

Comment: OP asks for starting screen saver **and** locking the screen.  Starting ScreenSaverEngine does not lock the screen.  You can test this easily.  Run the command and then move the mouse (or tap the keyboard).  You'll see that it's not locked.

Comment: To start the screensaver **and lock the screen**, you should set "System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Require password **immediately** after sleep or screen saver begins"

Comment: Note that as of macOS Sonoma beta 2 and 3, this method no longer works, while it will still launch the screen, pressing the keyboard/mouse will not trigger the lock screen locking you out until a reboot (pressing power twice may work as an out). I reported the issue to Apple, hopefully they will fix it for release.

Comment: @cwizou edited with new Sonoma command. it's the same tool just different invocation with `open` to make it work.

Comment: I haven't tried post beta, they may have fixed it @AlexanderKlimetschek ! You could launch it but couldn't exit.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a bash script that does exactly what you are asking for: [maclock](https://github.com/roubles/maclock)

It is called from the command line as follows:

```
maclock
```

Under the covers it calls:

```
open -a ScreenSaverEngine
```

It can also be used to mute the system, or put the display to sleep:

```
maclock --mute --display
```

Comment: "By default maclock will just launch the screen saver, but it can also mute the audio and put the display to sleep." I tried it and that's all it does. It can't really lock the screen. So the "and lock the screen" part of the OP has still not been answered.

Comment: @hmj6jmh thats controlled via a system setting to require password from screensaver https://support.apple.com/en-tm/guide/mac-help/mchlp2270/mac

Answer (score 7):

on macOS Monterey, run in terminal:

```
open -b com.apple.ScreenSaver.Engine
```

Comment: works on big sur 11.6.7 as well.