# Are the Screensaver and Screensaver Preview different processes?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, screensaver

Are the Screensaver and Screensaver Preview different processes and if they are how would I activate them with a bash command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i start the screensaver (and lock the screen) from the os x terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505198/how-can-i-start-the-screensaver-and-lock-the-screen-from-the-os-x-terminal)

Comment: Yes they are not the same process however if you want to start the Screen Saver from the command line you can simply use: `open -a ScreenSaverEngine`

Comment: Thanks for the responses but this is not really what I was looking for. A while back I found this amazing script to [run a screensaver as the desktop background](http://osxdaily.com/2011/01/22/set-a-screensaver-as-your-desktop-wallpaper) and I made an automator script to run this at login. But since then, my screensaver doesn't work and just stays on my desktop. Surprisingly, the screensaver will run when I hit the preview button in system preferences so I was wondering if I could call on that preview to open from a bash script.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the answer, the shell script is  ***/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine*** it will open and it is considered a different process than the ScreenSaverEngine.app.

Thank you all for your help.